# netbeans sync ftp and git branch switches

Tags: git, netbeans, synchronization

I'm using Netbeans to work remotely on a ftp website and locally I use git. Every time \I save a modification it gets uploaded to the website.

The problem appears when I try to switch branches. Netbeans see the modifications and starts to synchronize the code. This means that it uploads the entire site again.

If that website has newsletter, wordpress blog, you can imagine the mess I'm into and how long I have to wait after I make a branch switch.

Do you have am advice for me in order to work more cleanly and smarter.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I have this same issue.  Right now I'm just closing netbeans as I change branches and then opening it back up.  Not Ideal.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a git hook on the master branch and a git ftp synchronizer instead of netbeans built-in solution...

You can check whether you are committing master this way:

```
$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null) == "refs/heads/master"
```

There are several ftp synchronizers:

- https://github.com/BeezyT/git-ftp-sync
- https://github.com/ezyang/git-ftp
- ...

Maybe you can configure the sync in netbeans to do the same branch checking, but I don't use netbeans, so I cannot help in that. Check the manual and the config options by sync.